# Steps to build Android NDK openssl as static library

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I just fetched all the source code from AOSP and have recursively copied external/openssl/* to myproject/jni/libopenssl/. Next, I added the following lines in Android.mk:

```
 #build libcrypto.a
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 include $(LOCAL_PATH)/libopenssl/Crypto.mk
 ...
 LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcrypto_static
```

However, this creates a bunch of errors.

I am wondering if anyone has clear steps to build libcrypto_static from AOSP. I noticed that there are many forks on github for openssl. However, I would prefer to use the one from AOSP as it seems to have optimizations for arm as well as x86. Regards.

Comment: "I would prefer to use the one from AOSP as it seems to have optimizations for arm as well as x86..." - two thoughts here. First, OpenSSL knows OpenSSL best; and not AOSP. Second, AOSP provides a downlevel version, and you would probably benefit from using the latest version of the OpenSSL library.

Comment: I believe [Android Native Development Kit Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/android-native-development-kit-cookbook/book) from Packt Publishing has all the steps you need. They use samples of real libraries in the wild (a graphics library like libpng or libjpeg, if I recall correctly). You need to read Chapters 8 and 9. Fortunately, Packt Publishing offers the chapters for free online as a sample to the book.

Comment: I forgot to mention... The OpenSSL wiki has a page on building the library from the command line at [OpenSSL and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android). It uses/requires the Android NDK (it just does not use Android's modified build system). The instructions are used to build [noloader/openssl-1.0.1h-android-18](http://github.com/noloader/openssl-1.0.1h-android-18). However, its *not* "`libcrypto_static` from AOSP".